# How do I catch errors using flutter's .then() method?

Tags: android, asynchronous, flutter, dart, future

I am using the Fluttery geolocator plugin to convert cooredinates into an address when a user searches for them.
However, when invalid coordinates are used, an exception is thrown but this is not handled as expected (code below).

```
void placemarkFromCoordinates(latitude, longitude) async {
    Widget address;
    Geolocator().placemarkFromCoordinates(latitude, longitude).then((result) {
        print("result $result");
    }).catchError((error, stacktrace) {
        print(error);
    });
```

When an error is thrown, the error should be printed. However, the catch block is never reached and I am left with this exception:

Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(ERROR_GEOCODING_INVALID_COORDINATES, Unable to find an address for the supplied coordinates.)

This error should be caught, but is not!

Answer (score 0):

Geolocator flutter plugin has a catchError method, so use that instead of then